# Como leer un archivo.xml en su formato original php

Tags: php, xml, curl

necesito capturar en una variable un archivo.xml (por ejemplo factura.xml) en su formato original XML, para poderlo enviar., pero no logro hacerlo.

dejo el formato del xml que necesito enviar (de esa misma forma que aparece el xml tengo que guardarlo en una variable para poder enviarlo) pero la mayoria de desarrollo en simplexml lee solo la informacion sin importar las etiquetas.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<GTDocumento Version="0.1" xmlns:cex="http://www.sat.gob.gt/face2/ComplementoExportaciones/0.1.0" xmlns:cfc="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/CompCambiaria/0.1.0" xmlns:cfe="http://www.sat.gob.gt/face2/ComplementoFacturaEspecial/0.1.0" xmlns:cno="http://www.sat.gob.gt/face2/ComplementoReferenciaNota/0.1.0" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dte="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/0.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/0.2.0 GT_Documento-0.2.0.xsd">
    <SAT ClaseDocumento="dte">
        <DTE ID="DatosCertificados">
            <DatosEmision ID="DatosEmision">
                
                <DatosGenerales CodigoMoneda="GTQ" FechaHoraEmision="2021-03-24T03:03:03" Tipo="FACT"/>
                
                <Emisor AfiliacionIVA="GEN" CodigoEstablecimiento="1" CorreoEmisor="test@test.com" NITEmisor="97151300" NombreComercial="emisorComercial" NombreEmisor="emisor">
                    <DireccionEmisor>
                        <Direccion>1</Direccion>
                        <CodigoPostal>2</CodigoPostal>
                        <Municipio>3</Municipio>
                        <Departamento>4</Departamento>
                        <Pais>GT</Pais>
                    </DireccionEmisor>
                </Emisor>

                <Receptor CorreoReceptor="test@test.com" IDReceptor="18221025" NombreReceptor="jorge santizo">
                    <DireccionReceptor>
                        <Direccion>1</Direccion>
                        <CodigoPostal>2</CodigoPostal>
                        <Municipio>3</Municipio>
                        <Departamento>4</Departamento>
                        <Pais>GT</Pais>
                    </DireccionReceptor>
                </Receptor>
            
                <Frases>
                    <Frase CodigoEscenario="1" TipoFrase="1"/>
                </Frases>
                
                <Items>
                    <Item BienOServicio="B" NumeroLinea="1">
                        <Cantidad>9.0</Cantidad>
                        <UnidadMedida>UNI</UnidadMedida>
                        <Descripcion>item1</Descripcion>
                        <PrecioUnitario>6.0</PrecioUnitario>
                        <Precio>54.0</Precio>
                        <Descuento>0.0</Descuento>
                        <Impuestos>
                        
                            <Impuesto>
                                <NombreCorto>IVA</NombreCorto>
                                <CodigoUnidadGravable>1</CodigoUnidadGravable>
                                <MontoGravable>48.21</MontoGravable>
                                <MontoImpuesto>5.79</MontoImpuesto>
                            </Impuesto>
                        </Impuestos>
                        <Total>54.0</Total>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
                <Totales>
                    <TotalImpuestos>
                        <TotalImpuesto NombreCorto="IVA" TotalMontoImpuesto="5.79"/>
                    </TotalImpuestos>
                    <GranTotal>54.0</GranTotal>
                </Totales>
            </DatosEmision>
        </DTE>
    </SAT>
</GTDocumento>
```

Comment: Buenas. Con cargar en su formato original, ¿te refieres a cargar todo el fichero en una variable y que todo el contenido se tome como un string simplemente sin utilizar librerías para procesado XML? Si es así, prueba con `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

La función que buscas es **simplexml_load_file()**

```
<?php

if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
 
    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
?>
```

*https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php*

Comment: El problema es que me devuelve un array, yo quiero que conserve el formato original del XML.

Comment: Alguien que pueda ayudarme???

Comment: print_r($xml->asXML() )